# JavaFX8 Calendar

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls, javafx-8

I've seen JavaFX8 has a DatePicker built-in. The thing is that I only need the calendar, without the textField. There's a way I can access only the Calendar view without the DatePicker or I have to make my own custom control?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Open Source library providing some controls based on the new Date and Time API. Maybe you find it useful. You can read more about it here:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/12/drombler-commons-date-and-time-controls.html

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/04/drombler-commons-javafx-controls-for.html

Comment: So there is no way to access the calendar view in the default JavaFX library right?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.